# AttachTo: "root component cannot be attached to other component in the same actor" when trying to spawn weapon at character socket

Tags: mesh, unreal-engine5

I'm pretty new at Ue5. I tried to follow a YouTube tutorial about making FPS game with Unreal Engine. I'm now stuck with an error when trying to spawn a weapon at my character newly created socket.

My newly created "WeaponSlot" Socket:
[image]

The code:
[image]

Error log:
[image]

From what I noticed, the only difference in code is "AttachTo" function, it should be "AttachToComponent". But there is no such function.

[image]

I'm super new to Unreal Engine. Any suggestion, or maybe another method to spawn the gun is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. You have to return target actor like so :
[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).